# Why is .ToList() a bottleneck compared to a Cast? Sample code follows

Tags: c#

http://codepaste.net/4xzv9k  is the codepaste link that shows the C# code (Sorry but I could not get the code to look right here)

My question is why a simple query like the following is so much faster as a cast rather than a .ToList extension:

```
    //fast:
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
              var queryShortWay1 = productList.OrderBy(a => a.ProductName).Where(a =>
                a.ProductName.Length < 99);

            mySecondProductLst = queryShortWay1 as List<Product>; //fast CAST  


        }

    //slow:

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var queryLongWay1 = productList.OrderBy(a => a.ProductName).Where(a =>
              a.ProductName.Length < 99);
            MyProductList = queryLongWay1.ToList();  //slow 

        }
```

You would think that .ToList is not that much slower, but it is by at least an order of magnitude.  Any reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine the first is fast because it is just setting `mySecondProductLst` to `null` since `queryShortWay1` is not a `List<Product>` (it is most likely of type `IQueryable<Product>` or `IEnumerable<Product>`). The query is not executed here.

The second "slow" example is actually executing your query.

The real key here though is LINQ query execution is *deferred* - meaning the query will not actually be executed until it is iterated over, whether by a loop, a call to `ToList()`, or some other means. That is, setting the variables `queryShortWay1` and `queryLongWay1` alone does not cause query execution.

Comment: OK, you are correct Ic  Indeed the 'fast' way is not doing anything but creating mySecondProductLst = null.  The good news for me is that I've been doing it the 'slow' way (correct way) for years, but I thought I just stumbled upon a faster way, but I was wrong.  Will accept your answer as correct.